# Firebase messaging, Failed to determine project ID for Messaging

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

How can I initialise my app for messaging? I keep getting the error

**"Error: Failed to determine project ID for Messaging. Initialize the SDK with service account credentials or set project ID as an app option. Alternatively set the GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT environment variable."**

when I try and invoke `messaging`

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

const config = {
    type: "service_account",
    project_id: "xxx",
    private_key_id: "xxx",
    private_key:
        "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----xxx-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
    client_email:
        "firebase-adminsdk-8dd2o@pushmessage-bd1eb.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    client_id: "107357357611247077666",
    auth_uri: "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    token_uri: "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    auth_provider_x509_cert_url: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    client_x509_cert_url:
        "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/firebase-adminsdk-8dd2o%40pushmessage-bd1eb.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
};

admin.initializeApp({
    config
});

const db = admin.firestore();
const messaging = admin.messaging();

const message = {
    data: { title: "Testing", body: "Test" },
    tokens: registrationTokens
};

messaging.sendMulticast(message).then(response => {
    console.log(response.successCount + " messages were sent successfully");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These lines don't make sense:

```
const db = admin.firestore(functions.config().firebase);
const messaging = admin.messaging(functions.config().firebase);
```

I'm not sure what you're intending to do by passing that parameter to `admin.firestore()` and `admin.messaging()`.

If this is running in Cloud Functions, perhaps you meant to initialize the Admin SDK like this:

```
const admin = admin.initializeApp();
```

and use it like this:

```
const db = admin.firestore();
const messaging = admin.messaging();
```

Comment: I can't get the projectid from the json, I keep getting the error